# Get transaction count per day

Tags: php, magento, stripe-payments

Im working with Magento and Stripe right now and developing a statistics module. In that module i want to know the amount of charges per day. I got a solution, but its really slow. Is it really neccesary to get Charge:all for get this number? Its really heavy data.

My solution so far:

```
public function getPaidInvoicesByDate($begin, $end) {
    Mage::log('BEGIN: ' . $begin . ' END: ' . $end, null, 'customerLog.log');
    $begin = strtotime($begin);
    $end = strtotime($end);
    $end = strtotime('+1 day', $end);

    $transactions = array();

    $this->setStripeKey();

    // Get alle invoices
    $charges = \Stripe\Charge::all(array(
        "limit" => 100,
        "created[gte]" => $begin,
        "created[lte]" => $end
    ));

    foreach ($charges->autoPagingIterator() as $charge) {
        $createdAt = explode(' ' ,date('d-m-Y H:m:s', $charge->created))[0];

        $transactions[$createdAt] += 1;
    }

    return $transactions;
}
```

Hope any of you got a suggestion how i can lower the loading time?

Answer (score 0):

Pagination requires you to loop over all transactions to count them. A better solution would be to use [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) instead.

Whenever something happens in a Stripe account such as a customer creation, a charge or a transfer we send an event to the webhook endpoint (if any) so that it's aware of it. You could listen for `charge.*` events and keep track of those in realtime in your own database. This would avoid having to paginate the API daily.